# Where would a Distributed Hash Table be used in place of BitTorrent?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, dht

The lack of recent research into the field of [DHT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Hash_Table)s in comparison to [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) ([Tribler](http://www.tribler.org/trac/wiki) being the most significant research project) has lead me to wonder about the usage of DHTs.

Both BitTorrent and Distributed Hash Tables provide a method for distributing content among peers using a key-value like datastore. What are the use cases where a DHT would be more applicable than using BitTorrent?

Comment: What do you mean that "BitTorrent provide[s] a method for distributing content among peers using a key-value like datastore"? As far as I knew, BitTorrent was just a nifty file transfer protocol wrapped around peer discovery methods (trackers, DHT, PEX, etc.). Are you referring to infohash-->data as the key-->value store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitTorrent and most file sharing applications are built on unstructured peer-to-peer overlay networks.

A DHT is a structured peer-to-peer network overlay.

Structured and unstructured peer to peer networks differ mainly in their routing algorithms. Unstructured P2P networks rely on flooding or heuristic searches. Searches aren't necessarily guaranteed to find a file that its looking for.

Whereas with a DHT (structured P2P network), barring a network error or some abnormality, it is guaranteed a file stored under a given key will be found on request. (I've done a lot of performance testing with free pastry and its extremely reliable)

A DHT would be more suitable to applications where the file stored in the P2P network MUST be found. With BitTorrent, I guess it's not essential that each file is found by every request.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean that "With BitTorrent, I guess it's not essential that each file is found by every request." ? How does BitTorrent locate files at all?

Comment: I don't know about BitTorrent in particular. I'm sure if you google it you'll find the answer fairly quickly. I know that BitTorrent is an unstructured p2P network. Algorithms differ throughout different networks.

Comment: When I hear "unstructured P2P network" I imagine Gnutella, where corresponding nodes would just flood queries/information to eachother in hopes of finding files. BitTorrent on the otherhand has a fairly rigid system of finding peers (either via a tracker, its DHT, or PEX). What do you mean by "BitTorrent is an unstructured P2P network"?